# my header location doesn't work even if my condition is recognized?

Tags: php, header

I don't know why my header location is not working. I tried to add an "echo "something"" in the condition of `$access` is true, but nothing happens. but my `var_dump($access)` returns a true or a false correctly.

```
public function appel(array $submit, array $signin)
    {
        $access = $this->model->getLogin($submit);
        var_dump($access);
        if($access){
            header("location: index.php?controller=category&action=list");
        }
        $this->view->form();
        

        $this->model->inscrit($signin);
     }
```

Comment: Don't output anything before sending the location header.

Comment: what do you mean about output?

Comment: even if you output (echo /print ) a space character before the location header statement, the location header redirection will **FAIL**

Comment: ok but there is nothing before the location

Comment: The `var_dump` or `echo` you're doing to confirm the value of `$access` will output text.

Comment: @VictorBriand _ANY_ text outputted on your page will break your header call.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
    if($access){
        ini_set("display_errors",1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        header("location: index.php?controller=category&action=list");
    }
```

Maybe your output started somewhere before so that the header could not be sent.